# How can i get precision & recall instead of accuracy in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, recurrent-neural-network

I'm seeing Spam Prediction classifying messages as Spam and Ham made by other person.

[source code]
https://github.com/nfmcclure/tensorflow_cookbook/blob/master/09_Recurrent_Neural_Networks/02_Implementing_RNN_for_Spam_Prediction/02_implementing_rnn.py

The program produces the following values. (loss, accuracy)

[Veiw Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF8HY.png)

In this code, the result is only loss, accuracy,

I think Accuracy has no meaning.
I need Precision, Recall value (for F1 measure)

However, since the my code analysis is not working properly,
I know Precision and Recall.
But I do not know how to calculate(code embedding) Precision and Recall in this code.

Comment: I can't understand what your question is. Please try to restate.

Comment: Sorry. Because I'm not that good at english. Thank you for your comment. I have made a correction, but I do not know if the question is understandable. In conclusion, what I want is a code that can output Precision or Recall.

Comment: Your edit is good. -1 removed.

Comment: Thank you !!! @EvanWeissburg

Answer (score 5):

I succeeded it myself, hurray !!

here is the code:

```python
actuals = tf.cast(y_output, tf.int64)
predictions = tf.argmax(logits_out, 1)

ones_like_actuals = tf.ones_like(actuals)
zeros_like_actuals = tf.zeros_like(actuals)
ones_like_predictions = tf.ones_like(predictions)
zeros_like_predictions = tf.zeros_like(predictions)

tp_op = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(
      tf.logical_and(
        tf.equal(actuals, ones_like_actuals), 
        tf.equal(predictions, ones_like_predictions)
      ), 
      "float"
    )
)

tn_op = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(
      tf.logical_and(
        tf.equal(actuals, zeros_like_actuals), 
        tf.equal(predictions, zeros_like_predictions)
      ), 
      "float"
    )
)

fp_op = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(
      tf.logical_and(
        tf.equal(actuals, zeros_like_actuals), 
        tf.equal(predictions, ones_like_predictions)
      ), 
      "float"
    )
)

fn_op = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(
      tf.logical_and(
        tf.equal(actuals, ones_like_actuals), 
        tf.equal(predictions, zeros_like_predictions)
      ), 
      "float"
    )
)
```

I saw confusion matrix open source in github thank you @Mistobaan !!
https://gist.github.com/Mistobaan/337222ac3acbfc00bdac

Comment: Good job in answering your first question and posting also the code instead of just the link. You should accept your own answer, too (nothing wrong with this - on the contrary, [it is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)